# ggplot or qplot histogram in R

Tags: r, histogram, ggplot2

I know this is pretty much a basic question, but I have some trouble in drawing histograms from a single vector containing these numbers (dat):

`30.90 31.00 32.75 32.65 32.50 31.60 31.80 30.70 31.20 28.10 29.50 28.60 31.70 33.10`

The qplot is straight forward:

```
qplot(PorData,  binwidth=1.0, geo="histogram", xlab="Data", ylab="Frequency")
```

This gives me a default histogram:
[image]

I would love to do a bit more aesthetically pleasing histogram, which would also contain a density curve showing the skewness of the data and to change the bin colors with a black outline, somewhat like this one:
[image]

Is it better to use the qplot function or the ggplot?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `qplot` is just a simplified `ggplot` function, they work the same but provide different interface. Notice that this kind of questions are off-topic on CV since they are not about statistics etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an approach to create a histogram together with a density curve in `ggplot2`.

The data:

```
dat <- scan(textConnection("30.90 31.00 32.75 32.65 32.50 31.60 31.80 30.70 31.20 28.10 29.50 28.60 31.70 33.10"))
```

The plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
qplot(dat,  binwidth = 1.0, geom = "histogram", xlab = "Data", ylab = "Frequency",
      y = ..density.., fill = I("white"), colour = I("black")) +
  stat_density(geom = "line")
```

Here, `y = ..density..` is used to use relative frequencies on the y axis.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very very much!!! I thought "...density..." was just a sample statement, when I was reading tutorials. Thanks!!

Comment: If I want to change the white fill to the default light red collor, how can I do it without the legend that appears automatically?

Comment: Thanks! But I don't get the idea how to use the aes() with a single vector. Every tutorial I've been reading uses data frames.